# SQL - Sharing fields between derived tables

Tags: sql, derived-table

Is it possible to access fields across derived tables?

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT ID, COL1A FROM Table1) T1
       JOIN (SELECT ID, COL2A FROM Table2) T2
           ON T1.ID = T2.ID
       JOIN (SELECT ID, (COL3A + T2.COL2A) AS SUM FROM Table3) T3
           ON T1.ID = T3.ID
```

Comment: Yes, are you getting an error in the code above?

Comment: Yes, it is. Or you can use Common Table Expressions (CTE) too.

Comment: I don't where the "yes" comments come from.  `T2.COL2A` is out of scope in ANSI SQL and every database I am familiar with.  There are better ways to write the query, but the specific expression is not permitted there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would put the expressions using multiple columns in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.COL1A, t2.COL2A, (t3.COL3A + t2.COL2A) as sum
FROM Table1 T1 JOIN
     Table2 T2
     ON T1.ID = T2.ID JOIN
     Table3 T3
     ON T1.ID = T3.ID;
```

There is no need for derived tables at all.